# Manually Set Windows Explorer Menu Item Priority?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer

Basically I like to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> to create new folders in Windows Explorer but as you can see from the screenshot below, Hg Workbench and WinMerge will both take priority over the "New" menu.

[image: Hg Workbench taking priority]

Is there a registry setting or some other way I can manually specify the priority of the Windows Explorer menu options?

I realise in this particular case that I can disable the shell integration for HgWorkbench and Winmerge so that the "New" menu will be hit first but I'd rather not have to rely on individual application functionality.

Comment: Not what you're looking for but **CTRL+SHIFT+N** will create a new folder in the current directory in Explorer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this'll work but you can give it a shot. It won't re-order the context menu but it may let you use your current New Folder shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) without Hg Workbench interfering with it.

Check that the context menu item for Hg Workbench is present under:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AllFileSystemObjects\ShellEx
or
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers
```

<sub>Source: [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-clean-up-your-messy-windows-context-menu/)</sub>

Edit the `(Default)` string value of the relevant key. It should be something like `Hg &Workbench`. Put the ampersand before a letter that you'd want to be its new shortcut key (e.g. `&Hg Workbench`) and yo'd have changed the keyboard shortcut for opening Hg Workbench context menu to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>